# Javascript remember variable, strip div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the a script which adds a word to a div on mouse-over now I want the word to be remembered and printed in the console when clicking on the word. 
But the words are links like:
 `<a href"">So,</a>`

When I click on the word, the script now remembers the whole thing with the link. So I need to find a way how to "strip" it down to just the word "So" any ideas?
 Here the code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

<script>
var $allescheissehierrein = $('.allescheissehierrein'),
    datenbank = {
    1: '<a href="file:///Users/shirin/Desktop/A/Media%20Design/TCB/one.html">So,</a>', 
    2: '<a href="file:///Users/shirin/Desktop/A/Media%20Design/TCB/one.html">HERE,</a>'},
    simbol = '',
    platzierRandom = function () {
      var w = document.body.offsetWidth,
          h = document.body.offsetHeight,
          rd = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

      for (var c = 0, l = rd.length; c < l; c++) {
        if (rd[c].className !== 'random') {
          continue;
        }

        var xCoord = Math.floor(Math.random() * w),
            yCoord = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);

        switch (true) {
          case (xCoord >= w - rd[c].offsetWidth - 10):
            xCoord = w - rd[c].offsetWidth - 10;
            break;
          case (xCoord <= 10):
            xCoord = 10;
            break;
          case (yCoord >= h - rd[c].offsetHeight - 10):
            yCoord = h - rd[c].offsetHeight - 10;
            break;
          case (yCoord <= 10):
            yCoord = 10;
            break;
        }

        rd[c].style.left = xCoord + 'px';
        rd[c].style.top = yCoord + 'px';
      }
    };

//einfach loop mit bis 100 oder was auch immer
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {

  //einen div in eine variable speichern
  //es wird für die datenbank "data-hover" auf den i wert gesetzt welcher ja stetig hochzählt darum alle verschieden
  switch (true) {
    case (i < 24):
      simbol = '#';
      break;
    case ((i > 23) && (i < 47)):
      simbol = '**';
      break;
    case ((i > 46) && (i < 97)):
      simbol = '-';
      break;
    case ((i > 96) && (i < 114)):
      simbol = '1.';
      break;
    case (i > 113):
      simbol = '~~';
      break;
  }

  //diesen die dem allescheissehierrein-div appendieren (100 mal)
  $allescheissehierrein.append('<div data-hover="' + i + '" class="random"><p>' + simbol + '</p></div>');
}

//diese platzier dings funktionion erst nach der platzierung aller divs (diese 100) machen weil sie ja vorher gar nicht existieren
platzierRandom();

//richtig mit jquery UND datenbank
$('.random')
  .hover(function () {
    var hoverdata = $(this).data('hover'),
        satzvondatenbank = datenbank[hoverdata];
    $(this).append($('<span>' + satzvondatenbank + '</span>').show('slow'));


      $( 'a' ).mousedown( function( event )
  {
       var poemArray;
  if ( localStorage.getItem( "poem" ) )
  {
      poemArray = localStorage.getItem( "poem" );

      console.log( poemArray );
  }
  else
  {
      poemArray = "";
      localStorage.setItem( "poem", poemArray );
  }

  poemArray += " " + satzvondatenbank;

  console.log( poemArray );


  localStorage.setItem( "poem", poemArray );

  }
  )



  }, function () {
    $(this).find('span:last').remove();
  });











  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no `<a>` shown in the html code. Click on what? What does *"remember"* mean. You need to make this question far clearer and remove any code not relevant to the problem ... whatever that is

Comment: No need to be rude. Was simply trying to point out that the question was not clear nor does it represent a [mcve]. Suggest you take a few minutes to read [ask] also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can navigate to the anchor tag using jquery and then get the text using jquery like this,

```
var anchorText=$("a").text();
```

This will fetch the innerText which is present inside the anchor tag.
Or you could use this method as well,

`var anchor=<a href="file:///Users/shirin/Desktop/A/Media%20Design/TCB/one.html">So,</a>`

```
anchor.substring(indexOf(">")[0],indexOf("<")[1]);
```